# Customize Bibliography Style

Tags: biblatex

This MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=7.5in, margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{filecontents}{bib}
@Article{NALE,
  Title                    = {Puzzles: Choose a Curtain, Duelity, Two Point Conversions, and More},
  Author                   = {Barry Nalebuff},
  Journaltitle             = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  Volume                   = {1},
  Year                     = {1987},
  Issue                    = {Fall},
  Number                   = {2},
  Pages                    = {157-163}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{first-last}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib}

%\usepackage[tufte, emptyfirstpage]{blackenedtitles}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est alia eirmod no, at has graecis molestie luptatum. Menandri maluisset usu in. Vim cu ceteros luptatum, in mel doming equidem docendi. Timeam volutpat vix ad, vidit albucius duo ne, sed cibo probo ex. No sit meis novum, mel ullum nonumy et, pri an agam eirmod doctus.\footfullcite{NALE}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

How can I further customize the style so as to:

1. A comma follows the author name (instead of a period),
2. A comma follows the title, but the comma being inside of the quotes,
3. Journal title followed by a comma, and then Vol. ##, No. ##
4. Followed by comma, and the rest as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the description it seems that you want to have a comma as separator between the units in a the bibliography. The appearance of this separator is encoded in the `\newunitpunct` command. Thus we can redefine it, namely:

```
\renewcommand{\newunitpunt}{\addcomma\addspace}
```

For the treatment of the interaction between punctuation marks and quotes, `biblatex` recommends to use  the `csquotes` packages. The required behaviour is the traditional american one, so we can achieve the result by loading `babel` with the `american` option (or use the setting of `csquotes`).

Finally, to formatting of the journal title and publication information is controlled by the `volume+number+eid` bibmacro.  Here, we can first declare two auxiliary macro for the format of the volume and number and then we can change the `volume+number+id` macro (taken from `standard.bbx` file from  the biblatex distribution).

The full MWE now looks like:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=7.5in, margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{filecontents}{bib}
@Article{NALE,
  Title                    = {Puzzles: Choose a Curtain, Duelity, Two Point Conversions, and More},
  Author                   = {Barry Nalebuff},
  Journaltitle             = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  Volume                   = {1},
  Year                     = {1987},
  Issue                    = {Fall},
  Number                   = {2},
  Pages                    = {157-163}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{first-last}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}


\newbibmacro{volume}{%
  \iffieldundef{volume}{} 
    {\bibcpsstring{volume}\addnbspace\printfield{volume}}}
\newbibmacro{number}{%
  \iffieldundef{number}{}    
    {\bibcpsstring{number}\addnbspace\printfield{number}}}


\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \usebibmacro{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}


\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib}

%\usepackage[tufte, emptyfirstpage]{blackenedtitles}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est alia eirmod no, at has graecis molestie luptatum. Menandri maluisset usu in. Vim cu ceteros luptatum, in mel doming equidem docendi. Timeam volutpat vix ad, vidit albucius duo ne, sed cibo probo ex. No sit meis novum, mel ullum nonumy et, pri an agam eirmod doctus.\footfullcite{NALE}
\end{document}
```

and the outcome is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. 1) Is it possible to have the comma following the title **inside** the quotes; 2) I get empty Vol. and No. when those fields are empty.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand 1). 2) is easy.

Comment: The comma following the title, is outside of the curly quotes, can it be inside?

Comment: The comma is already inside, see the picture.

Comment: Don’t how/why, out in my case. Thanks a lot any way.

Comment: Do you load `csquotes` and `babel` with `american` option?

Comment: I had \usepackage[english]{babel}, changing it to \usepackage[american]{babel} did it. Thanks.